# Iframe discord - widgetbot - results in "error ahoy"

Tags: iframe, discord, widget

I am adding discord channels via `<iframe>`from [wigetbot](https://docs.widgetbot.io/tutorial/iframes/)

Code:

```
<iframe src="https://e.widgetbot.io/channels/<server-id>/<channel-id>" height="372px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I am getting these errors inside the widget (inconsistently):

[image: Error Ahoy!]
[image: Error loading messages - communication problems with discord]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just because widgetbot is very busy, and has many users trying to use it at once.

There's not much you can do about it besides trying again later.